# return во вложенной функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Как вернуть из функции test значение data.reponse[0].uid ?

```js
function test(targetUid){
VK.api("users.get", {uids:shortName,fields:"photo_50"}, function(data) 
    { 
     return data.response[0].uid;
    
    });    
}

var nick = "123123";
console.log(test(nick));
```

Comment: О нет, опять... :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, то ли ещё будет...

Answer (score 0):

например так:

```js
function test(targetUid, dataObject, onDataRecieved) {
   VK.api("users.get", {uids:shortName,fields:"photo_50"}, function(data) { 
      onDataRecieved(dataObject, data.response[0].uid);        
   });    
}

function onNickDataRecieved(dataObject, data) { 
   dataObject.result = data;
}

var nick = "123123", nickData = {};
test(nick, nickData, onNickDataRecieved);
nickData.result && console.log(nickData.result);
```

а вобще почитайте про [промисы](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) - они предлагают более удобный интерфейс для работы с асинхронным кодом